# Download set of images from database and display it in Picturebox C# using HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

First of all before somebody says that this question is not valid as there are answers and advice me to Google first; I have tried almost all solutions on Internet but not able to figure out what to do next. So, let me explain a bit about my question.

I have one database (MS SQL 2012). I have established a connection with one of the table from that database like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("myconnectionString"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,Filename FROM somedatabase WHERE Type = 'specified multiple types using OR'", connection))
            {
                t1.Load(cm.ExecuteReader());
                foreach (DataRow row in t1.Rows)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < t1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(row[i].ToString() + " ");
                    }

                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Above code is under some button1_click() and it is working properly. Now my real question is, I want to show images from this table into PictureBox. What I am trying right now is as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://somelink");
                 request.Method = "GET";
                 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                 request.CookieContainer = container;


                 response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                 Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                 byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
                 int read, total = 0;

                 while((read = stream.Read(buffer,total, 1000)) != 0)
                 {
                     total += read;
                 }

                 Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer,0,total));
                 pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Above code is under different button_click(). There are no errors, warnings or anything. But after clicking the button, nothing is showing up in picturebox. Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try stepping through your code in the debugger. I tested it and it worked fine. Make sure it's actually being called and returning a valid image (you may want to try `bmp.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);`.)

Comment: I'm still confused on how SQL is related to your problem.

Comment: So instead of displaying it in Picturebox through stream, you are saying I should save it first and then display in picturebox using FromFile(Filename) ?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I have tagged SQL in case there is some problem with MS SQL Server connection which can be figured out only by someone who knows SQL well

Comment: What I'm suggesting is first seeing that you're actually getting a valid image response. Stepping through the call is probably the best (easiest) way to figure out why it's not working for you.

Comment: So you trying to test it with image from them web instead of from the table to figure out why you are not getting an image from database? Can you list your code when you trying to get image from database.

Comment: @NickGotch Ya I would do that, but just one question. These two codes are under different Button_Click(). Does that matter?

Comment: Where you say "http://somelink", make sure that the link in your real code points to an actual valid image file. I tested with "http://www.commongroundonthehill.org/i/Instruments/Fiddle.jpg".

Comment: @VladimirOselsky I am trying to use HTTP from a table in database that is stored on some cloud service.

Comment: What's the connection between the two methods? Does the DB call return an image link that you plug into the other call? They can work together but it depends what you're passing between them.

Comment: @NickGotch Yes it is working for images on Internet. I also tried on random image on Google. But its not working for image in database.

Comment: @GauravK. That's a different issue then. You need to get the bytes returned from the DB and convert them into a `Bitmap`. Then you can assign that to the `PictureBox`. The `WebRequest` isn't what you want to use in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working just fine as it is. The only change needed was in size of byte[] array. It was set to byte[100000] however, it was needed to be set to higher value as images that I am trying to access were of higher resolution and thus higher size. Thank you everyone for help.